# store chat session in db to persist them after server reboot

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm implementing a socket.io chat server and I currently have the sessions stored in memory so that if the user disconnect and reconnect he will get again the same session identifiers. This is done "in memory" so when I restart the node server all the information are lost and the users get a new identifier.

I am trying to save each user data in the db also and when the server restart re-build the map with the data from the db instead of starting from a new one.

On connection I do:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // persist session
  sessionStore.saveSession(socket.sessionID, {
    userID: socket.userID,
    username: socket.username,
    connected: true,
  });

  // emit session details
  socket.emit("session", {
    sessionID: socket.sessionID,
    userID: socket.userID,
    username: socket.username
  });
```

on the client side when i receive the info I save them on the database.

`sessionStore` is a custom node module I import this way: `const { InMemorySessionStore } = require("./sessionStore");` and its code is the following:

```
/* abstract */ class SessionStore {
  findSession(id) {}
  saveSession(id, session) {}
  findAllSessions() {}
}

class InMemorySessionStore extends SessionStore {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.sessions = new Map();
  }

  findSession(id) {
    return this.sessions.get(id);
  }

  saveSession(id, session) {
    this.sessions.set(id, session);
  }

  findAllSessions() {
    return [...this.sessions.values()];
  }
}

module.exports = {
  InMemorySessionStore
};
```

I think that I should replace `this.sessions = new Map();` with something that will retrieve the data from the db and build the map from it but I am wondering how to do it. I talk to the db with the `mysql2` module but it is available on the server and not inside this module

How can I do it?